# why am i not getting post api body inside multer request body in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a `node.js` based server in which i have `addProduct` api in which i am receiving an object and image files also.

in my `api.route.js` file i am doing like this

```
import { Router } from "express";
import { log, loggedIn } from "./middlewares/index";
import { addProduct, getAllProducts, getProductById, updateProduct, deleteProduct } from "./handlers/product";
const multer = require('multer');
const uploadFolder = 'uploads/';
const fs = require('fs');


var storage = multer.diskStorage({
destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    // console.log(req.res, 'name')
    // console.log(Object.keys(req), 'keys')
    if (fs.existsSync(`uploads/${req.body.categoryName}`)) {
        cb(null, `uploads/${req.body.categoryName}`);
    } else {
        fs.mkdir(`uploads/${req.body.categoryName}`, err => {
            if (err) {
                console.log('err in creating folder', err);
            } else {
                cb(null, `uploads/${req.body.categoryName}`);
            }
         });
       }
     },
      filename: (req, file, cb) => {
       cb(null, file.originalname);
      }
     });

  var upload = multer({
     storage: storage
  })

router.post("/", log, upload.fields([{ name: 'image' }, { name: 'cover_image' }, { name: 'thumbnail_image' }]), addProduct);
```

And in my `product.controller.js` i am doing like this

```
export async function addProduct(req, res) {
let productImages = [];
try {
    let body = parseBody(req)
        // console.log('----body----', body)
    if (body) {
        console.log(req.files, 'files')
        if (req.files['image']) {
            req.files['image'].forEach(item => {
                productImages.push(item.filename)
            })
            body.images = pictures
        }
        if (req.files['cover_image'] && req.files['thumbnail_image']) {
            body.coverImage = req.files['cover_image'][0].filename;
            body.thumnbnailImage = req.files['thumbnail_image'][0].filename;
        }

        let product = await saveProduct(body)
        if (product) {
            generateResponse(product.success, product.message, product.data, res)
        }
    } else {
        generateResponse(false, "Please provide complete info", null, res)
    }
} catch (err) {
    console.log('----------Error---------', err)
    generateResponse(false, 'Error occured, 404 not found!', err, res)
   }
 }
```

I have `angular7` on client-side and have image upload like this in `component.html`

```html
<form enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <input type="text" name="name" nbInput fullWidth placeholder="Name" [(ngModel)]="product.name" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <nb-select [(ngModel)]="product.category" name="category" class="type-select" style="display: initial;" (selectedChange)="getBrands()">
                <nb-option value="1">Select Category</nb-option>
                <nb-option *ngFor="let category of allCategories" value="{{category._id}}">{{category.displayLabel}}</nb-option>
            </nb-select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <nb-select [(selected)]="product.brand" name="brand" class="type-select" style="display: initial;">
                <nb-option value="1">Select Brand</nb-option>
                <nb-option *ngFor="let brand of categoryBrands" value="{{brand._id}}">{{brand.name}}</nb-option>
            </nb-select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <tag-input [(ngModel)]="selectedSizes" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" theme='bootstrap' placeholder="Enter sizes" secondaryPlaceholder="Enter sizes"></tag-input>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <tag-input [(ngModel)]="selectedColors" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" theme='bootstrap' placeholder="Enter colors" secondaryPlaceholder="Enter colors"></tag-input>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <input type="text" name="desc" nbInput fullWidth placeholder="Description" [(ngModel)]="product.description" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <input type="number" name="price" nbInput fullWidth placeholder="Unit Price" [(ngModel)]="product.price" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <input type="number" name="quantity" nbInput fullWidth placeholder="Quantity" [(ngModel)]="product.quantity" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <input type="number" name="discount" nbInput fullWidth placeholder="Discount (Option)" [(ngModel)]="product.discount" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="custom-file mb-3">
                <input type="file" name="thumbnail" class="custom-file-input" id="customFile" (change)="onThumbnailImageChanged($event)" [(ngModel)]="product.thumnbnailImage" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
                <label class="custom-file-label" id="ti">Select Thubnail Image</label>
            </div>
            <p *ngIf="isFileError" style="color:red;font-size:11px">{{fileErrorMsg}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="custom-file mb-3">
                <input type="file" name="cover" class="custom-file-input" id="customFile" (change)="onCoverImageChanged($event)" [(ngModel)]="product.coverImage" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
                <label class="custom-file-label" id="ci">Select Cover Image</label>
            </div>
            <p *ngIf="isFileError" style="color:red;font-size:11px">{{fileErrorMsg}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

The issue which i am facing is that i am receiving object and images files in the `product.controller.js` in `req.body` but inside my `api.routes.js` in `multer` storage function i am not getting my body object in `req.body`. Because in my `req.body` i want to get my object with the help of which i have to construct a path for image uploading. How can i get my body inside `multer` storage function?

Comment: Did you set the enctype of your form to 'multipart/form-data' ?

Comment: @CamilleSébastienNiessen no i have updated my question. I also included my client side part in my question.

Answer (score 0):

Your'e sending a file with your form using a POST request. You should set `enctype="multipart/form-data"` as attribute on your form when you're sending file input to your server.

[Here you can find the specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.2)

Comment: i have updated my question and included my whole `component.html` code also you can see i also added your recommended  `enctype="multipart/form-data"` but still i am getting empty body inside my ``multer.diskStorage function inside `api.routes.js`

Comment: In your POST router, you ask in upload.fields[..] for 'image', 'cover_image' and 'thumbnail_image', I don't see those names back in your HTML form. Can you make sure the name attributes of your form match the field names in your upload.fields middleware? So in your form for example your'e using name="thumbnail" and not name="thumbnail_image"

Comment: issue here is that i am not getting object  inside multer function. I am getting image files correctly , there is nothing wrong with image file. I am just not receiving object which i am sending from client side along with these images

Comment: So the only other thing I can think of right now is that you need to use body-parser as well to receive all other data as well:

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

Comment: i am already using `app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: config.app['bodyLimit'] }));` in my app's `index.js` so do you thing that still i need to use this  `app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}))` ?

Comment: Yeah you need it to parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded data, which is the way browsers send form data in POST requests

Comment: still getting empty object in multer function. Now i have doubt that either post request body either accessible in multer req or not

Comment: In addProduct the req should have the body values, not in the multer function

Comment: the whole issue is this that i want post request body inside multer function. Please see my code in my question. Is it possible to get post request body inside multer function?

Comment: As far as I know about this, don't blame me if I'm wrong, is that the order of the input fields matter here. So if you'll put the file inputs before all other fields, you should be able to access the other props of the form in req.body inside the multer functions. It's a matter of order as far as I know. But this is the last thing I can think of to help you further. > Edit > Or how the FormData is ordered when sending it to the server